# Hyperlink in Evolus Pencil 3 - I can't get it to link

Tags: evolus-pencil

I have created 2 page layouts.  The target page was exported with the "Single web page" option and "Default HTML".  In the parent page I drag the hyperlink object to the page but I can not find anyway to link it to the target page.  I have researched the question and can find answers for the pencil 2 version but those solution don't work in 3.  Thank for your help.